# TypeScript API for SourceFile creation: how to get syntactic errors information

Tags: api, typescript, syntax-error

TypeScript API `Program` has method `getSyntacticDiagnostics` to get syntactic errors. But if there is no `Program`, just `SourceFile` how can I get the same kind of information?

I created `SourceFile` through

```
function createSourceFile(fileName: string, sourceText: string, languageVersion: ScriptTarget, setParentNodes?: boolean, scriptKind?: ScriptKind): SourceFile;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that `fileName` (string) parameter in createSourceFile is virtual file name. This fileName (string) is used globaly while using TypeScript library.

The most important thing what you need is what doc comment on `createProgam` method says. **A Program is an immutable collection of 'SourceFile's and a 'CompilerOptions' that represent a compilation unit.** `createProgam` method as first parameter requires list of strings which are virtual names of files used in this program.

If you don't understand previous 2 theoretical paragraphs I think that comments in sample will help you.

```
// this is the real code of file. Use fs.readFile, fs.readFileSync or something other to load file real source code.
var code = "class 1X {}";

// I will use this virtual name to reference SourceFile while working with TypeScript API.
var virtualFileName = "aaa.ts";

// initialize SourceFile instance
var sf = ts.createSourceFile(virtualFileName, code, ts.ScriptTarget.ES5);

// Make program as collection of my one virtual file
var prog = ts.createProgram([virtualFileName], {});

// process response as you need.
console.log(prog.getSyntacticDiagnostics(sf));
```

Comment: If you get errors about `Cannot read property 'text' of undefined` then you may also want to add the fourth parameter (`setParentNodes`) to `createSourceFile`, i.e. `ts.createSourceFile(virtualFileName, code, ts.ScriptTarget.ES5, true);`